# how do i check if my program is connected with my MSQL database in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

Hello I'm a student and I'm stuck on a part I need to check if the problem is with my connection or with my code please don't tell me if something is wrong with my code just help me in the right direction what kind of way should I use to check if my MySql database is connected? And yes I deactivated the rest of the code to check if its the code.

```
 private void Btnlogin_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; user id = root; Password =''; Database = login; SslMode=none");
        Debug.WriteLine(con);
        /* MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) from users where id='" + Txtusername + "' and pword='" + Txtpassword + "' ", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {

            this.Hide();

            main ss = new main();
            ss.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("failed to login please check your username and password");

        }*/
```

Comment: Start by calling `con.Open()`. It will throw an exception if connecting fails. Then use a `try...catch` block to handle that exception and show a message to the user for example.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnection_State.htm

Comment: @ADyson thank you i was looking for that for hours but could not find it now i know my connection works and i need to find the problem in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            command.CommandTimeout = 60 * 5;
            using (MySqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    //Reading code..
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Notes about this code:

1) Always use `using` statements when you have `IDisposable` objects

2) The `connection.Open();` instruction, will try to open the connection to your DB. If it won't work, it will throw and exception which will be catched by the `try...catch` defined in this code

Answer (score 0):

namespace projectname
{
    public partial class login : Form
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("connection string here");

```
    public login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }



    private void freshrationpurchase_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "select count( *) from user where id=@";
        SqlDataReader dr;
    dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
        cn.Close();

    }
}
```

}